# Amp- iframe in amp Lightbox or amp-accordion

Tags: amp-html

I need to insert an external application on amp-lightbox, amp-accordion or other amp-tag. The application is inserted in external html because the code isn't compatible with amp-html code.
What is the solution for this problem? The iframe doesn't work correctly inside other amp-*, when I insert the iframe inside amp-* the page show the loading bullets but not load content, if I insert the code outside it works correctly.

This application is launched when the user click to a specific area or button because on first time the iframe must be hidden for user.

Thanks You

Example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-lightbox" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-lightbox-0.1.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-iframe" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-iframe-0.1.js"></script>
  <link rel="canonical" href="https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-lightbox/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
  <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
  <style amp-custom>
.lightbox {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.lightbox h1 {
  color: white;
}
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
<amp-lightbox id="my-lightbox" layout="nodisplay">
  <div class="lightbox" on="tap:my-lightbox.close" role="button" tabindex="0">
  <amp-iframe width="350" height="300" layout="responsive" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-popups" frameborder="0" src="https://www.xxxxxxxxx.com"></amp-iframe>
  </div>
</amp-lightbox>
<button class="ampstart-btn caps m2" on="tap:my-lightbox" role="button" tabindex="0">
Open lightbox
</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The area is sufficient for the application

Comment: Is your iframe loaded with https:// ?

Comment: Are you leaving the correct amount of space? It would be helpful if you provide your code sample so we don't have to imagine what might be wrong.

Comment: @lovntola, yes the iframe and the page loaded (the page aplication) are https pages.

Comment: @JayGray the example code is inside the post, by copyright I can't publish  real url for the iframe.

Comment: OK, I think I see the problem. The iframe must be a minimum  distance from the top of the page. It can't be at the top of the page. But there is systematic way around that requirement. I need to look in my notes/examples to find the code. Will post it back here when I find it.

Comment: Thanks  @Jay Gray, I detect other aditional problem, the page of iframe and the url of the applicative can't be to same domain "www.xxx.com", only works on subdomain or other domain... :(

Answer (score 3):

The

```
<script async custom-element="amp-iframe" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-iframe-0.1.js"></script>
```

is missing. See [here](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-iframe/).

Comment: Yes correct, I forgot to copy this line in post but it isn't the problem. 
I'm going to correct the post code.

Comment: Can you try the iframe with layout="fixed" insteed of responsive.
I use this as a workarund to Display ad about the fold.

Comment: Or have you a CORS Problem?
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS